# localizationDelegates throws Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter

When using `flutter test`, `context.localizationDelegates` throws an exception. Application runs fine on device and emulator. I was following the guide on pub.dev for easy_localization package. Only things I had to add were `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `ScrollConfiguration`. But even if I put them away, it does the same. I think it has to do something with the `context`. `BuilderHome` uses `FutureBuilder` as I am pre-loading big json files when the app loads. This is the whole code where it is used.

```
**imports**

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  **init of shared preferences values**

  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      path: 'assets/translations',
      startLocale: const Locale('en'),
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en'), Locale('ru'), Locale('cs'), Locale('pl'), Locale('de'), Locale('fr'), Locale('es'), Locale('pt'), Locale('ja')],
      saveLocale: true,
      useOnlyLangCode: true,
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => Settings(...),
        child: const App(),
      )));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
        supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
        locale: context.locale,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: InvisibleScrollBehavior(),
            child: child!,
          );
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: const Color(Values.colorEE),
            textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(selectionColor: Color(Values.colorContentTextLight), selectionHandleColor: Color(Values.colorContentTextDark)),
            fontFamily: 'Manrope'),
        home: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [Expanded(child: Container(color: Color(Values.colorPrimary), child: const BuilderHome()))]));
  }
}
```

Here is the result of `flutter test`. `widget_test` file is the same from the creation of the project.

```
The following _CastError was thrown building App(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
   App App:file:/.../widget_test.dart:8:35

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      BuildContextEasyLocalizationExtension.localizationDelegates (package:easy_localization/src/public_ext.dart:148:32)
#1      App.build (package:cotwcompanion/main.dart:56:41)
.
.
.
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 5 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)
```

And the function throwing the error in the `public_ext`.

```
List<LocalizationsDelegate> get localizationDelegates =>
  EasyLocalization.of(this)!.delegates;
```

I am so sorry if this is duplicate, but I did not find any similar problem.

Comment: EasyLocalization.of(this) is null and you are using (!) to ensure that it is not null.

Comment: That I know. I would like to know why it is null. As I mentioned I am using package from pub.dev. I followed the Example. I assume the (!) is there from its developers and that it is intended.

Comment: In my case I called `runApp` twice by mistake, but for you it's not the case. Maybe `ChangeNotifierProvider` is a problem, because I removed it from your sample and it worked.

Comment: did you fix it?